# Flutter iOS notification send click_action

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, messaging

We are developing with flutter for both android and iOS in a mobile application. We have been on a problem for about 2 months and we could not solve it. The problem is;

When we click on the notification we sent, no action is taken on the iOS side and a black screen appears. This system, which works smoothly on the Android side, does not work on the iOS side. After some research we got here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages

We made an edit according to this link, but the notifications still do not work properly on the iOS side.

This is the message code we sent.

```
const message = {
    token: token,
    notification: {
      title: username,
      body: lastMessage,
      click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
    },
    data: {
      specificPageRouteId: lastSender.toString(),
      chatId: chatId.toString(),
      notificationType: "chat",
      messageType: messageType,
      click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
    },
  };
```

There are not working, the above is also not sending the notification correctly. But the main problem is the click problem in the incoming notification.

```
      const message = {
    token: token,
    notification: {
      title: username,
      body: lastMessage,
    },
    data: {
      specificPageRouteId: lastSender.toString(),
      chatId: chatId.toString(),
      notificationType: "chat",
      messageType: messageType,
      click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
    },
  };
```

Is there anyone who can help us with this?

Comment: have you handled on click notification event at iOS side. ?

Comment: Yes, it already works fine on the android side. But I couldn't manage to add click_action in iOS part.

Comment: @SpeedyG1481 hey, have you solved the issue? Experiencing something similar, but without a black screen. Android seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes we have resolve this issue. The problem was on the firebase side. It got fixed when we used the new API. I think the new one is not very stable.

```
admin.messaging().sendToDevice( tokens,

  {

    notification: {
      title: title,
      body: body,
    },

    data: {
      click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
      notificationType: "TYPE",
    },
  },
  {
    content_available: true,
    priority: "high",
  }
);
```

This code works.